# Calling method within a Class

Tags: class, methods

I have a program with a class in it, then in that class there is another class and within that  class there is a method. I am trying to call that method inside the class. 
Basically: Method is in Class B which is in Class A.

```
Class A
    Class B
        Method
```

Class B:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    public void getLibraryData () throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("" + username [0] + ".txt"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("" + username [0] + ".txt", true));
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
        {
            songs [count] = line;
            artists [count] = reader.readLine ();
            categoryA [count] = reader.readLine ();
            count++;
        }
        data = new Object [count] [];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {
            Object[] row = data [i] = new Object [3];
            row [0] = songs [i];
            row [1] = artists [i];
            row [2] = categoryA [i];
        }
    }
    private String[] columnNames = {"Song",
        "Artist",
        "Category", };

    private Object[] [] data = {
        };

    public int getColumnCount ()
    {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount ()
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName (int col)
    {
        return columnNames [col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt (int row, int col)
    {
        return data [row] [col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass (int c)
    {
        return getValueAt (0, c).getClass ();
    }
}
```

I am trying to call getLibraryData().

Answer (score 0):

Call A needs a getter method like `getB()` then you could the method of an B instance. Or you crate a deferral method in A like `getLibraryDataInB()`, or you just rewrite your code and don't have boxed classes liked that, if they have to be accessed from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the inner class and call the method.
Here you go.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html